# How much time has passed between The Last Jedi and The Rise of Skywalker?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, the-rise-of-skywalker

*The Rise of Skywalker* takes place sometime after *The Last Jedi*. It doesn't pick up straight after because the Resistance has a new base and is running operations again. Rey is also in training and seems to have read her way through the Jedi texts quite well so there is some not insignificant time skip.

How long of a time skip is there?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Approximately 1 year later.

The [Rise of Skywalker Visual Dictionary](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker:_The_Visual_Dictionary) contains a timeline of Finn's life.

The Battle of Crait, seen at the end of *The Last Jedi*, takes place on 0 ASI (After Starkiller Incident). The mission to the Sinta Glacier Colony, seen at the start of *Rise of Skywalker* takes place in 1 ASI. Since the smallest unit used in these timelines seems to be .5 of a year, the longest the gap could be is 17 months.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "*the smallest unit seems to be .5 of a year*"?

Comment: @desertnaut - There are various other timelines strewn around the book, but none of them use a unit smaller than .5 of a year to indicate when various events happened. The Battle of Crait is a hard date (since it happened almost immediately after the Starkiller Incident). If the Glacier Base mission had been more than 16 months later, the timeline would read **1.5**

Comment: What do BSI and ASI mean?

Comment: @Martha - After Starkiller Incident. It's what the makers of the new trilogy have replaced BBY and ABY (After Battle of Yavin) with

Comment: Are there 10 months in a Star Wars year?

Comment: Oops. 12 months in a year, obvs

Comment: I thought maybe there were 10 months, it is based in a galaxy far far away, after all ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 18):

According to [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_IX_The_Rise_of_Skywalker#Synopsis), *The Rise of Skywalker* starts:

> A year after the [battle of Crait](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Battle_of_Crait)

which is roughly when *The Last Jedi* ended. Said battle occurred in 34 ABY, while the first episode of *The Rise of Skywalker*, namely the [mission to obtain the Sith wayfinder](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mission_to_obtain_the_Sith_wayfinder) by Kylo Ren and the Knights of Ren, occurred in 35 ABY, i.e one year later.

This conclusion seems to be based upon testimony by John Boyega (the actor playing Finn) in a relevant article by *Empire* in February 2019:

> John Boyega has confirmed the film takes place roughly one year after the events of *The Last Jedi*.

Full article:

[image: page 82 of Empire magazine's February 2019 issue]

There is an awful lot of secondary reports on this, but the sole primary source seems to be the above quote by Boyega in *Empire*, as tweeted [here](https://twitter.com/starwarstuff/status/1076323027644702720):

[image: tweet from starwarstuff: "John Boyega has confirmed that Star Wars: Episode IX takes place ONE YEAR after the events of 'The Last Jedi'."]

As for Boyega himself, when asked in Twitter, [replied](https://twitter.com/JohnBoyega/status/1077126691988951040) that he actually doesn't remember:

[image: tweet from JohnBoyega: "I don't even remember having the interview (five laughing emojis) (shrug emoji) I'm tired it's been a long few months."]